# Swift: How Do I Stop A Pan Gesture from Cancelling When a Timer Fires?

Tags: swift, timer, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

This question is brief and I don't believe it requires showing code, but I'd like to learn why my app is doing this.

In my ViewController, I have a countdown `Timer` that fires every second and updates a label in the view with `seconds -= 1` (for example). Everything's working perfectly as it should... no big deal.

But, I also have a UIButton in this same view that I can drag around. The problem occurs every time my `Timer()` fires (every second)... My PanGesture (dragging the UIButton) is cancelled and the UIButton is dropped.

Is there a certain property that I need to set on either the `UIButton` or the `Timer` to prevent this from happening?

Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: it would be easier to visualise if you can show us your code. thanks.

Comment: cause for cancel is not because of Timer , you can verify by stoping Timer and see gesture is working fine without it ?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh That's correct. If I turn the timer off, I may continue to drag the UIButton around the screen no problem. But when the timer is active and I drag the UIButton, every second (when the timer fires) the touch is cancelled and the UIButton is dropped... If I touch and start dragging it again, the firing timer will make me drop it again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try pan gesture in separate thread ?

Comment: let me know if it works..

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m fairly new to Swift... what do you mean by a separate thread? Right now, both my Timer and my UIButton are in the same ViewController file (same class)... I’m very sure that’s not what you mean by thread though, right? :P lol

Comment: Are you just updating label when timer is fired ? Or updating button which is being dragged ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I’m only updating the label. The button is independent from anything the timer is doing.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Putting the panGesture on a different thread didn't work for me, and likewise trying to put the timer on a different thread. I have however narrowed it down to the updating of the text on the label that's the issue. If I instead print the updated value to the console with each timer fire and don't update the label, the pan gesture is fine. The label and the button aren't related in any way (other than the fact that they're on the same screen), so is there a reason that updating the UI (text on a label) would cause an active pan gesture to cancel?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I haven't been able to discover the reasoning behind it, here's what's I've learned:

- If you are in the middle of a UIPanGesture (dragging a UIView around) and you try to update the text on a label (ie. update the UI), your UIPanGesture will cancel and `.ended` will be called. This was happening for me every second when my timer was updating the text on the label.
- In my application, the label showing the countdown value is originally hidden (`alpha = 0`) in my view even when I am performing the text updates on it, and my UIButton to drag around is only visible when my countdown label isn't.
- So my workaround was to only update the text on the label when it's actually visible. That way, my UIPanGesture isn't affected while I can drag it around, but when the `label` becomes visible and my UIButton isn't, then I can update the text on the `label` as desired without worrying about dragging the UIButton around.

I know it's a very custom fix that works for me, but if anyone knows what causes the issue, please do share :)